# Find total children for each parent

Tags: mysql

I am trying to find out how many reports each manager has within an organisation but cannot quite get it to work for me.

Here is an example dataset - this is all within one table and each row has a manager except the first who is top of the tree:

```
ID  Manager
1   NULL
2   1
3   2
4   3
5   3
6   5
7   5
8   5
9   5
10  3
```

I need the result to come out as:

```
Manager  Count
1        1
2        1
3        3
5        4
```

This is what I have so far but it is not giving me what I need:

```
select e1.manager, count(e3.id) as emp_count
  from employee as e2
left outer
  join employee as e1
    on e1.manager = e2.id
left outer
  join employee as e3
    on e3.manager = e1.id
group
    by e1.manager
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you have so many outer joins?

```
select e1.manager, count(e1.id) as emp_count
from employee as e1
where e1.manager is not null
group by e1.manager
```

From the data you provided, there is nothing to do with "parent and child" in your question.  It's a very simple aggregate.  If that's not the case, please update your question with better sample data.

Comment: I took an example I found online and tried to modify it for my requirements - the parent/child is probably not the correct way to define this but I was thinking that each manager is the parent and their reports are children. Either way this works a treat so thank you

Comment: Just so you know, when we say "parent/child," we are usually referring to nested relationships, such as where managers have managers of managers.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's as simple as this:

```
select manager, count(manager)
from employee
where manager is not null
group by manager
```

Comment: You have a typo.  `count(manager)` when grouping by manager will give you a count of 1 every time. :)

Comment: It worked in T-SQL, but you're right, the question is in MySQL so the answer could be different. However, I'd still be surprised since the results are grouped by manager.

Comment: If you are grouping by manager, then there is one manager per group.  The count is per group.  Therefore, the count of one manager per group equals one.  I will make sure to stay away from T-SQL in order to avoid whatever strange craziness results in anything else. :)